# How can I enable PHP within the Apache service configuration in Nixos?

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm using the following config:

```
services.httpd =
  {
    enable = true;
    adminAddr = "localhost";

    extraModules =
    [
      "http2" 
    ];
    enablePHP = true;

    virtualHosts =
    [
      {
        hostName = "localhost";
        documentRoot = "/var/www/html/html-geo";
        serverAliases =
        [
          "localhost"
        ];
        enableSSL = false;
      }
    ];
  };

  users.users.http =
  {
    isNormalUser = true;
    home = "/etc/user/http";
  };
```

However this results in the following error:

> Mar 21 15:23:44 nixos httpd[21707]: httpd: Syntax error on line 69 of
>   /nix/store/dp6kc224raib72dk8g2lahrr3a1drk8j-httpd.conf: Cannot load
>   /nix/store/bp2jirc0zwa46rb3xm62xjc8bsvknavc-apache-httpd-2.4.35/modul>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  {name = "php7"; path = "${pkgs.php}/modules/libphp7.so";}
```

I needed to add the above into `extraModules`.